# Choosing enum element using "..."

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement

Is '...' symbol is a c language keyword?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    A=0,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,M
} alpha;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    alpha table = C;

    switch (table)
    {
        case A ... D:
        /* I have never seen "..." grammar in textbook */
            printf("Oh my god\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("default\n");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is `...` allowed in C for range?

Comment: I think it is specific to gcc compiler, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not standard C, but a GCC extension:

> You can specify a range of consecutive values in a single case label, like this:
>
> ```
> case low ... high:
> ```
>
> This has the same effect as the proper number of individual case labels, one for each integer value from low to high, inclusive.

More in [GCC extension: Case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges)

Answer (score 1):

This is called *Case Ranges*. And no, this is **not** a standard C feature.

It is implemented as [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html). This is just another way to use [*fall-through* `case` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).