# Is this C18 base switch case?

Tags: c

I was going through the latest code in the Linux kernel, when I found a `switch` written differently.

```
kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_main.c Line number 3524
```

As per my C knowledge, `switch/case` needs to be written as

```
case e1000_undefined: // enum value as 0
case e1000_82542_rev2_0: // enum value as 1
case e1000_82542_rev2_1: // enum value as 2
         // code
```

But in kernel code I found it like this:

```
case e1000_undefined ... e1000_82542_rev2_1:
         // code
```

Is this C18 coding style for C?

Can someone point me a resource (book/GNU man pages) to understand more about C18?

Comment: What makes you think it's C18?

Comment: other duplicates: [what does this syntax of switch case mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699746/995714), [Are triple dots inside a case (case '0' … '9':) valid C language switch syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7043788/995714), [Are Elipses in case statements standard C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5924681/995714), [Choosing enum element using “…” (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37318196/995714)

Comment: The "c18" tag is for "MPLAB C Compiler for PIC18 MCUs"  , is that what you are asking about?  (Not to be confused with ISO/IEC 9899:2018)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case ranges are a [GCC extension for C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html).

Comment: Thanks, then what is C18 ? where can I get to know more ? I want to understand difference between C18 and old C (C98/C99)

Comment: You may start with [C's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)).

Comment: @Rohit These will also help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c (see tiny links: "
C89, C95, C99, C11, C17, C23") and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/history